# How is this matrix inconsistent? Guass-Jordan elimination.

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: Matrix]

Why can I not do something like… add 1x row 3 to row 2 and add 1/4 row 3 to row 1 in order to get zeroes in a13 and a23? The calculator seems to ignore -2 as the 3rd pivot.

Answer (score 1):

The last line represents the equation $0 = -2$, which is never true. Therefore no equivalent system of equations will ever be consistent. Also, there is no such thing as a "third pivot", as your system only consists of two unknowns. (Your system is represented by a $3\times 2$ matrix which is augmented.)

Comment: I didn't realize that the calculator required the last column to be b in its Gauss-Jordan elimination.

Answer (score 0):

The matrix you are using in the calculator is seen as an extended matrix, as shown by the columns names. Here "$b$" is supposed to be the independent term. Your system is $3\times 2$, and it is inconsistent, as the calculator says.

Comment: Thank you. I feel pretty foolish, but I can't even find my keys when they're right in front of me so this isn't surprising.